# anchor tag clickable area larger than image inside

Tags: html, css

Seen this question asked quite a few times, but seems like solutions work for some but not others:

Code is as follows:

```css
.headbuttons {
  opacity: .7; 
  background-color: grey; 
  background-blend-mode: overlay; 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="headbuttons" id="homebutton" href="C:\Users\Dom Nguyen\Documents\website.html"> 
<img src="C:\Users\Dom Nguyen\Documents\home_button.png" width="125" height="62.5"> </a>
```

Tried the suggested solution of inline-block and block to display but neither worked, clickable area still much larger than image itself.

Comment: but `display: inline-block;` working fine, can you reproduce, create a fiddle or something, as here [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/xuj7ccyj/1), its working fine.

Comment: You need to set `width` and `height` for anchor tag also `width: 125px; height: 62.5px;`

Comment: No, there's no need to set un-necessarily h/w for `a` tag.

Comment: strange, works in fiddle but not so when i try in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your css to the following, which includes width and height:

```css
.headbuttons {
  opacity: .7; 
  background-color: grey; 
  background-blend-mode: overlay; 
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 62.5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="headbuttons" id="homebutton" href="C:\Users\Dom Nguyen\Documents\website.html"> 
<img src="C:\Users\Dom Nguyen\Documents\home_button.png" width="125" height="62.5"> </a>
```

Comment: your solution's correct with one change: as opposed to applying these class settings to the anchor tag, I applied them to a newly created img class tag and that worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set  with width and height, something look like:

`<a width="125" height="62.5">`

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by [Luka Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39361451/18284107) surely works for this particular use case. However, as a general solution, you can just add the css property `display: block;` to your `<img>` tag and the `<a>` around it will automatically scale to the size of your `img` (even when its size changes).

```css
.headbuttons {
  opacity: .7;
  background-color: grey;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  display: block;
}

.headbuttons img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="headbuttons" id="homebutton" href="C:\Users\Dom Nguyen\Documents\website.html">
  <img src="C:\Users\Dom Nguyen\Documents\home_button.png">
</a>
```